# iTunes Connect - Strange refund in Sales & Trends in

Tags: app-store-connect

I have app with subscriptions (week, month & year). Yesterday in my stats appears strange refund.
In Subscription -> Summary I see 1 refund

[sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyYqy.png)

In Sales -> Units I see "-8" in graphics and -4 in stats if I fltered by territoty.

[unit1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk85f.png)

[unit2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI1D5.png)

I don't understand what this mean. Is it correct ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please embed the images instead of linking to external sources?

Comment: hi, images embeded